# Как воспользоваться методом SoundPool.Load во фрагменте. Что указать вместо this?

Tags: java, android

```
package dorof.testeng.frame;

import android.app.Fragment;
import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.media.AudioManager;
import android.media.SoundPool;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Button;

import dorof.testeng.DataBaseHelperFor;

/**
 * Created by Al on 19.05.2015.
 */
public class beginner_level1_1 extends Fragment {
    DataBaseHelperFor dbHelperfor;
    SQLiteDatabase sdbfor;
    public SoundPool mSoundPool;
    public int   mTimeSound;
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        mSoundPool = new SoundPool(10, AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, 0);

        View v =  inflater.inflate(R.layout.beginner_level1_1, null);
        Button ADD1 = (Button) v.findViewById(R.id.clear1);
        Button sound1 = (Button) v.findViewById(R.id.sound1);

        mTimeSound = mSoundPool.load(this, R.raw.otime,1);

        ADD1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {

                ContentValues newValues = new ContentValues();
                //значения для каждой строки.
                newValues.put(dbHelperfor.WORD_COLUMN, "people");
                newValues.put(dbHelperfor.TRANSL_COLUMN, "люди");
                // в базу
                sdbfor.insert("words_level1", null, newValues);
            }
        });

        sound1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

                mSoundPool.play(mTimeSound, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1);
            }
        });
        return v;


    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

1. Отформатируйте правильно код.
2. Прочитайте [дукументацию](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/SoundPool.html#load(android.content.Context,%20int,%20int)) по этому методу, там все написано (Нужно передавать объект типа `Context`)
3. Названия классов пишутся с заглавной буквы и без подчерков. Названия переменных - со строчной буквы. Прочитайте `Java Code Convention`

Comment: Спасибо за ответ. Все это было просмотрено, был применен метод getActivity(), но, к сожалению, ни по одному из нажатий этих двух кнопок не происходит ни воспроизведение, ни добавление записей. В чем может быть загвоздка, не подскажете?

Comment: @dorof, ну подебажьте, посмотрите логи... Кто знает, что у вас там нетак...

Answer (score 1):

`Context` во фрагменте можно получить вызвав метод `getActivity()`

Comment: Постарайтесь писать более развернутые ответы. Поясните, на чем основано ваше утверждение?